# How to switch repositories from one to the next

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, repository, github, fork

I was using a github repository from a previous developer.

I am the only coder on this project, so I forked the project over to my own github repository.

Now I would like to commit soley to my repo.

Unfortunately, I realized that I never changed my .git/config , so I was still committing to the old repo. I just changed it to the appropriate url, and when I type :

```
$> git status
```

It returns :

```
=> Working directory clean.
```

But I know its not because I have several commits I've made. So my local box has different code then what it is pointed to on my repository.

My question is this. Obviously I'm halfway through the process of doing this. Do I need to re-fork to update, and then I'm good. Or is there a special command I need to run to let my local box know its 'git status' command is targeting a new repo to compare itself to? Equally, am I missing something else very important :D ?

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`git remote`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) to manage your remote

- rename origin

```
    git remote rename origin old_origin
```

- add a new origin

```
    git remote add origin git://github.com/my/forked/repo.git
    git fetch origin # will create all the remote branches references 
                     # in your local repo
```

You can also easily [setup a new upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch) for your current master branch (git 1.7 and more):

```
git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
```

---

The "`nothing to commit (working directory clean)`" message of `git status` won't prevent you to push.
After changing the origin, you should see:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by xxx commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

That means you have some commits to push to your new origin.

---

Note: "[`git remote`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/20a5dd670c957fa59b420facf63abe61b6b2438a/Documentation/git-remote.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote))</sup> rename failed to rename a remote without fetch refspec, which has been corrected with Git 2.39 (Q4 2022).

See [commit 5a97b38](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a97b3810946440764a0a9a2292fcfdfa11391d5) (22 Sep 2022) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 20a5dd6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/20a5dd670c957fa59b420facf63abe61b6b2438a), 10 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`remote`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a97b3810946440764a0a9a2292fcfdfa11391d5): handle rename of remote without fetch refspec
>
> <sup>Reported-by: John A. Leuenhagen</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> We return an error when trying to rename a remote that has no fetch refspec:
>
> ```
> $ git config --unset-all remote.origin.fetch
> $ git remote rename origin foo
> fatal: could not unset 'remote.foo.fetch'
> ```
>
> To make things even more confusing, we actually *do* complete the config modification, via `git_config_rename_section()`.
> After that we try to rewrite the fetch refspec (to say refs/remotes/foo instead of origin).
> But our call to `git_config_set_multivar()` to remove the existing entries fails, since there aren't any, and it calls die().
>
> We could fix this by using the "gently" form of the config call, and checking the error code.
> But there is an even simpler fix: if we know that there are no refspecs to rewrite, then we can skip that part entirely.

Comment: Wierd. It returns "error: unknown option `set-upstream'" I wrote what you had their exactly.

Comment: @Trip: what version of git are you using? `set-upstream` has only been introduced since git1.7.

Answer (score 0):

`git status` only shows you the status of your working directory, not the entire repository. It seems like you only need to change the remotes that `git push` and `git pull` use by default. Open up `.git/config` and find your `branch.<branch>` entries and change them, as well as your `remote.<remote>` entries. For example, your `master` entry may look like this:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Just change `remote` to reference *your* (forked) remote.

Also, your remote entry may look like the following:

```
[remote "myremote"]
    url = git://github.com/me/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

You can add a `push` entry so that your `master` branch is pushed by default:

```
[remote "myremote"]
    url = git://github.com/me/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    push = master
```

Comment: Ok I did all that. But how do I push the new code I've written on my local on to my new repository if my current git status is clean?

Comment: Your `git status` is just the status of your *working copy* files. You push the repo using `git push`. If there are differences between your local repo and the remote repo, the changes will get pushed up.

Answer (score 0):

In whole, but I should include it in this answer. Is that before hand I manually altered my .git/config to include my new repository url. That's why I didn't have to rename or add any origin as Von suggested.

Then I just guessed this and performed

```
 $> git fetch origin
```

Which returned

```
From git@github.com:gotoAndBliss/hq_channel
 17326ca..043d395  master     -> origin/master
 * [new branch]      panda_streaming -> origin/panda_streaming
 + 6ec9bf8...becbcc6 testing    -> origin/testing  (forced update)
```

Then on git status I got

```
# On branch testing
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/testing' by 9 commits.
```

I git pushed origin testing, and I think I'm on target now.

Comment: right, I had forgot about the `git fetch` step. I have amended my answer to reflect that step.